# Creating buffer around stream network within raster layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, buffer

I have a raster layer of a stream network with two values (1 no stream, 0 stream). I need to create a 100m buffer around the entire stream network that lies within a specific watershed.shp. I have access to Spatial Analyst.
I've tried the expand tool and the polygon to raster tool with zero success.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: How do you define "zero success"?  What precise steps did you perform?  What error(s) or other unexpected symptom(s) did you encounter?  Have you performed searches using the term "raster to vector conversion"?

Comment: When I use the expand tool, a new layer is generated but it seems to expand into the entire area, meaning it doesn't just "buffer" around the streams, my entire stream.tif becomes one layer.

Comment: Is that not the same as raster to polygon? I guess it isn't. I will search for that. Thank you. I have also tried using the Euclidian distance tool, but I don't have a lot of experience working with raster data, so this is all very new to me.

Comment: Raster to vector is a collective term for "raster to polygon", "raster to line" and "raster to point".  I think it will help your question if you can include a picture of what you have and what you are trying to get.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I think I'm now on the right track. I used raster to polyline, and then created a 100m buffer. That seems to do what I want it to do. However, when I try and convert it back to a raster, I end up with a ton of values. I'm not sure what value to put under cell size.

Comment: That's a new question so it should be researched/asked as one.

Answer (score 1):

To do this I would convert [Raster to Polyline](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/raster-to-polyline.htm) dataset:

> Converts a raster dataset to polyline features

and then [Buffer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/buffer.htm) that polyline dataset by a value of 100m:

> Creates buffer polygons around input features to a specified distance.